Aligning/syncing one audio file to another using Python
I have 2 audio files recorded using laptop mic and one with external mic. Laptop mic recording starts after external mic. The time difference could be 2-60 seconds.
So I wrote this code which is pretty accurate, but when I bring both audio tracks (one from the video that uses laptop mic) and the newly adjusted audio, there is still like 50ms delay. Why could this be?

Sometimes it seems there is positive delay, and sometimes negative.

from scipy.signal import correlate
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve
from scipy import signal
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import mediainfo

import numpy as np

def findOffset(audio1, audio2):
    correlation = signal.correlate(audio2, audio1, mode="full")
    lags = signal.correlation_lags(audio2.size, audio1.size, mode="full")
    lag = lags[np.argmax(correlation)]
    
    return lag


def adjustAudio(audio_segment, lag, frame_rate):
    # Convert lag from samples to milliseconds, rounding to nearest integer at the last step
    ms_lag = round((lag / frame_rate) * 1000)
    
    if lag > 0:
        # Audio needs to start later: pad audio at the beginning
        silence = AudioSegment.silent(duration=ms_lag, frame_rate=frame_rate)
        adjusted_audio = silence + audio_segment
    else:
        # Audio needs to start earlier: trim audio from the beginning
        adjusted_audio = audio_segment[abs(ms_lag):]  # Use abs to convert negative lag to positive

    return adjusted_audio


def alignAudioTrack(audioFile, newAudioFile, lag):
    audio_data, rate, audio_segment = loadAudio(audioFile, return_segment=True)

    # Adjust the AudioSegment based on lag, ensuring frame_rate is passed correctly
    adjusted_audio = adjustAudio(audio_segment, lag, rate)

    # Fetch original bitrate
    bitrate = mediainfo(audioFile)['bit_rate']

    # Save the adjusted audio preserving the original bitrate
    adjusted_audio.export(newAudioFile, format="mp3", bitrate=bitrate)


audio1, rate1 = loadAudio(audioFile1)
audio2, rate2 = loadAudio(audioFile2)
lag = findOffset(audio1, audio2)
alignedAudioFile = os.path.join(newAudioDir, f"{baseName}_aligned.mp3")
alignAudioTrack(origAudioFile, alignedAudioFile,  lag)


maybe problem makes float values - maybe you should calculate it ((lag * 1000) / frame_rate). OR maybe you shouldn't use round()

try changing mode="full" to mode="same"

plot the results with matplotlib or whatever. your audio editor might cause this issue. -- [mre] would be more successful if you presented the source data required to reproduce the issue.

also... your [mre] makes no sense. alignedAudioFile is undefined.

@ChristophRackwitz it's not just display though when I play them starting at the same time there is double voice. alignedAudioFile is just the path of the new audio file.

@dankal I got worse results with same, but I will check again. full worked the best so far.
